# GND related - maybe off topic

Tags: power-supply, voltage, ground

Situation - listening to music via Bluetooth using an integrated amplifier.
I removed the GND wire from my pick up/turntable wich was connected to the amplifier. While removing it from the amplifier the end of the wire removed from the turntable touched the body of the amplifier and the sound stared to take some breaks, like losing signal from Bluetooth until I turned the amplifier off.
Question - Does that GND wire could have anything to do with the result in the way the music played?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! GND is the reference to your voltage, without GND your not going to have voltage refence therefore no voltage at that stage.

Don't mess with GND and/or Vcc in the circuit if you do not know what your doing, specialy hitting everything with the cable and when your powered on.

Now you gotta have faith and hope that you didn't fried your amplifier after properly reconnecting.

Comment: Well! It still works :) but I can t tell the difference if has any damage. One that I can notice (it didn't do this before ) is when I change the song it makes a white noise click(Don t know how to call it)